# Is there a faster way to perform conditions with a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, for-loop, dataframe, conditional-statements

```
df =
Idx  Var1 Var2 Var3
0     0    3    0
1    10    0    0
2     0    0    2
3     0    3    0
4     0    0    1
5    10    0    2
6     0    1    1
7     0    0    0
8     0    3    0
```

For example:

1. Start logging when Var1 > Var3
2. Once logging is started, if Var2 < Var3, start over from condition 1 again.
3. Else, Keep scanning until Var2 > Var3
4. If Var2 > Var3, mark it down
5. Do this process through the whole dataframe
6. Return df(all rows) with conditions met

So basically it should return only `8   0  3  0`  in this example. `0   0  3  0` is not it because condition 1 hadn't started yet. `3   0  3  0` is not it because `2   0  0  2` violated the condition 2, so it has to start from condition 1 again.

I have tried:

1. Loop df directly
2. Loop after converting to `list`
3. Loop after converting to `array`
4. `Iterrows` & `Intertuples`

The fastest method is #2 so far. Is there a faster way than that? Because I have many lines and heard make use of pandas vectors is faster. Thanks.

Comment: pandas vector is to make parallel processing by applying the given function on multiple records parallely. Your requrement depends on output of previous record. This a more like a state transition system. This cannot be parallelized. To effectively use pandas try to structure the problem such that every record has adequate information to evaluate the condition.